# What is the sheafification of the presheaf of the one point compactification?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, compactness, sheaf-theory

Okay, so I had this idea for a presheaf that is quite peculiar. Instead of being based on algebraic category (i.e. abelian groups), it is based on a topological one, the category of compact topological spaces.

Okay, so let's say you have a space $X$. An open space $U$ is associated with the its [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension), $U^*$. For each pair $V \subseteq U$, we have a continuous map $\text{res}_{V,U}: U^* \to V^*$ defined as

$$\text{res}_{V,U}(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if $x \in V$} \\
\infty & \text{if $x \in U \backslash V \vee x = \infty$}  \end{cases}$$

$\text{res}_{U,U}=\text{id}_{U^*}$ and $\text{res}_{U,V} \circ \text{res}_{V,W} = \text{res}_{U,W}$ trivially. Therefore, this forms a presheaf.

My question is what is the [sheafification](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~damek/ANoteOnSheafification.pdf) of this presheaf? (I'm hoping it will be some sort of localized compactification!)

Comment: tongue twister!

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but it's too long for a comment, so I'll post this as an answer and hope that nobody complains.

For simplicity, let's call your presheaf $\mathcal{F}$.

**First, let's look at the stalk:**

The stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$ is just going to be the direct limit (with respect to the restriction you defined) of the spaces $U^*$ with $U$ an open neighborhood of $x$. This is just going to be the space $$\mathcal{F}_x  = \left(\bigcap_{U \ni x} U\right) \cup \{\infty\}$$ with the topology in which the only non-trivial open set is $\{\infty\}$.

**A special case: the space is $T_1$**

That $X$ is $T_1$ is equivalent to the intersection of the neighborhoods around $x$ being $\{x\}$ for every $x$. In this case, $\mathcal{F}_x = \{x\}^* = \{x,\infty\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset,\{\infty\},\{x,\infty\}\}$. Recall that the sheafification $\mathcal{F}^{sh}(U)$ is a subset of $\prod_{x \in U} \mathcal{F}_x$, and in particular, since each $\mathcal{F}_x$ contains two distinguished points, this can be identified with the subsets of $U$, i.e. by looking at where this is not $\infty$. With this identification, $$\mathcal{F}^{sh}(U) = \{A \subseteq U \colon A~\mathrm{discrete}\}.$$ By a discrete space, I just mean every point is open. Restriction from $U$ to $V$ is just $A \mapsto A \cap V$.

**Remark**

Even for nice spaces, this sheafification will typically be pretty large. In particular, for our $T_1$ case, every finite subset is discrete!

Comment: I don't think the topology on the stalk is the discrete topology. I think x is the only closed point.

Comment: If infinity was closed in the limit this would imply the point x is open in each neighborhood which will not be true for a general T1 space

Comment: What is the topology on $F^{sh}(U)$? I specified we are in the category of compact spaces, not of sets. I would be fine relaxing the category to that of all topological spaces, but $F^{sh}(U)$ still needs a topology.

Comment: @Cubohr, you're right about the stalk having $x$ as the only closed point. Which means my general statement about $\mathcal{F}_x$ is also wrong. The strong topology in general will put $\infty$ as the only open point. Will edit accordingly.

Comment: @PyRulez: I forgot about the category! It's probably most direct to try to consider the universal property at this point? A first guess might be that the topology comes from being a subset of $\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_x$ where each $\mathcal{F}_x$ has the topology Cubohr pointed out (and which is now edited into my answer). But I'm not certain...

Comment: @KSackel: There is a natural continuous injection $\mathcal{F}^{sh}(U)\to\prod_{x\in U} \mathcal{F}_x$, but I don't see any reason to expect it to be a homeomorphism onto its image in general.  Note also that the topology on $\mathcal{F}^{sh}(U)$ will probably not be compact.  The correct topology on $\mathcal{F}^{sh}(U)$ is the topology that makes it the colimit over all open covers of the space of the limit of the values of $\mathcal{F}$ over the sets (and intersections of sets) in an open cover.

Comment: @Eric, I wasn't claiming for this injection to be a homeomorphism (it's obviously not surjective). I was suggesting that maybe $\mathcal{F}^{sh}(U)$ has the subspace topology inherited from this injection (although I don't think this is obvious and I'm not convinced it's true). Also, PyRulez suggested weakening to the category of all topological spaces, which I think is still an interesting question.

Comment: @KSackel: Yes, sorry, I meant that the continuous injection will probably not be a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Yes, I see that you doubly edited your comment and now I agree with you on all counts. :)

Comment: Actually, the description of sections of $\mathcal{F}^{sh}$ as discrete subsets holds even if $X$ is not $T_1$.

Comment: I guess it did locally compactify it, didn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This sheafification does not exist in general, at least if you want the target category to be the category of compact spaces.  To construct the sheafification of a sheaf, you need the existence of certain limits and colimits, and the category of compact spaces does not have all limits and colimits (in particular, it does not have all equalizers and does not have any infinite colimit such that the colimit computed in the category of all spaces is not compact).  For instance, suppose $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is the Cantor set.  A cofinal family of open covers of $X$ is given by $\mathcal{U}_n=\{\{x\}\times\{0,1\}^{[n,\infty)}:x\in\{0,1\}^n\}$, and all the sets in each $\mathcal{U}_n$ are disjoint.  It follows that we should be able to compute the value of the sheafification on $X$ as the sequential colimit of the spaces $Y_n=\prod_{U\in \mathcal{U}_n} U^*$, with the maps $Y_n\to Y_{n+1}$ given by the obvious restrictions.  But this colimit does not exist in the category of compact spaces (indeed, it is easy to see each map $Y_n\to Y_{n+1}$ is the inclusion of a proper clopen subset).

The example of the Cantor set was just used for the convenience of being able to explicitly write down a cofinal family of open covers.  In general, the same problem will arise for almost every space: for instance, in any $T_1$ non-discrete space $X$, there is no single finest open cover of $X$, and so the colimit that would describe the value of the sheafification on $X$ probably does not exist.

Comment: I can relax it to the category of all topological spaces.